# Proving ∀k{[P(1)⋀···⋀P(k)] → P(k + 1)} Natural Deduction

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, natural-deduction

This is what I have currently.

$\begin{array}{|l}\forall k [P(k)\rightarrow P(k+1)]\quad premise
\\\hline\begin{array}{|l} x_0
\\ P(x_0) \rightarrow P(x_0 + 1) \quad \forall \text{elim 1}
\
\\\begin{array}{|l} [P(1)\wedge\dots\wedge P(x_0)] \quad Assumption 
\\\hline P(x_0) \quad\wedge \text{Elim 4}
\\ P(x_0 + 1) \quad \rightarrow \text{Elim 3, 5} \\\end{array}
\\ [P(1)\wedge\dots\wedge P(x_0)] \rightarrow P(x_0 +1) \quad \rightarrow \text{Intro 4-6} \\\end{array}
\\\forall\{[P(1)\wedge\dots\wedge P(k)] \rightarrow P(k+1)\}\quad\forall \text{ Intro 2-7} \\\end{array}$

How would I get $P(1)\wedge\dots\wedge P(k)$? It doesn't make any sense for me on where these other elements will be coming from.

Would my overarching proof structure be correct?

Comment: The question is not clear. The statement in the title is not valid, and your premise appears to be unrelated to it. More importantly, formalised proofs should _never_ contain statements that include ellipses (...) as that is part of informal language only.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen the question was how to use natural deduction to prove induction and strong induction are equivalent. The answer is correct my original post had been edited to reflect the actual answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you need to have $[P(1)\wedge\dots\wedge P(x_0)] \rightarrow P(x_0+1)$  as the second to last line (i.e. the last line of the subproof) ... the $k$ only comes back in once you ad the universal quantifier on the last line.

And, given that you want to prove $[P(1)\wedge\dots\wedge P(x_0)] \rightarrow P(x_0+1)$, the inside subproof should assume  $P(1)\wedge\dots\wedge P(x_0)$, so that when you get to $x_0+1$, you can do a conditional proof and get $[P(1)\wedge\dots\wedge P(x_0)] \rightarrow P(x_0+1)$ as desired.

So, it should look like:

$\begin{array}{|l}\forall k [P(k)\rightarrow P(k+1)]\quad premise
\\\hline\begin{array}{|l} x_0
\\ P(x_0) \rightarrow P(x_0 + 1) \quad \forall \text{elim 1}
\\\begin{array}{|l} P(1)\wedge\dots\wedge P(x_0) \quad Assumption 
\\P(x_0) \quad \land \ Elim
\\ P(x_0 + 1) \quad \rightarrow Elim \\\end{array}
\\ [P(1)\wedge\dots\wedge P(x_0)] \rightarrow P(x_0+1) \quad \rightarrow Intro \\\end{array}
\\\forall k\{[P(1)\wedge\dots\wedge P(k)] \rightarrow P(k+1)\}\quad\forall Intro \\\end{array}$

OK ... and now I think it will become clear how you get $P(x_0+1)$ ...

Comment: Thanks for fixing my typo, but would that then literally be all that the proof requires or are there more in the first $\vdots$ that I am missing?

Comment: @AndrewRyan Well, note that I deleted your very most inner subproof where you assume $P(x_0)$ .... why don't you need that one?  How *do* you get to $P(x_0+1)$?

Comment: I honestly don't know why we wouldn't need that one since don't we need it to utilize the $\rightarrow$ Elim. For your second question - would we be using a $\rightarrow$ Elim to obtain $P(x_0 +1)$?

Comment: @AndrewRyan Right, we need $P(x_0)$ to infer $P(x_0+1)$ using $\to$ Elim... but rather than *assuming* $P(x_0)$, you can just *infer* $P(x_0)$ from $P(1) \land ... \land P(x_0)$ using $\land $ Elim

Comment: ah, so then what do we need before we make the assumption of $P(1) \wedge \dots \wedge P(x_0)$? or is there nothing and that is the actual proof?

Comment: @AndrewRyan We don';t need anything before that, no.  So yes, we just need that one extra step. I'll add it to my Answer